# sbpl_lattice_planner map resolution

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, resolution

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using the sbpl_lattice_planner package and I noticed that whereas it works fine when the map resolution is 0.025 (2.5cm), it always fail to find a solution when the resolution is 0.05 (5cm). So far, I just modified the resolution parameters in the motion primitive generator to have them consistent with the map. It seems that the performance of the planner are
affected by the resolution of the map, which shouldn't be the case if the motion primitives are changed accordingly.

Should I modify some other paramters?

Best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224708/sbpl_lattice_planner-map-resolution/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually this should be the other way around. Performance should be better, when to resolution is more coarse. The resolution of the map and motion primitives has to match, though. Besides that one explanation for not finding a solution might be that in the coarser solution no path exists.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-21**:
The default SBPL primitives do not provide good coverage of the space, so there are some positions that appear "near" the robot but are actually unreachable with coarse primitives.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-01-25**:
After we figured out that we work in the same lab, we debugged this offline. Unfortunately, I already forgot, what the issue was, but I believe something basic. @Federico: Can you follow up on this?